# C# unload image from imagebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method whit the following logic:

1. I delete all files from **input** and **output** folders
2. user selects an initial picture
3. this pictures as being assigned to **imageBox1**
4. picture is being copied to the folder **input**
5. magic happens to picture and I put it to the folder **output**
6. new picture from output is beign assigned to **imageBox2**

Here is where problem starts. When users wants to repeat operation imagebox1 and imagebox2 do have pictures assigned to them. And the step #0 failswith error

```
The process cannot access the file '03933.tiff' because it is being used by another process.
```

What I was trying is :

```
 private void CopyImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string pathInput = currentPath + "\\Input";
            string pathOutput = currentPath + "\\Output";


               if (pictureBoxInput.Image != null) { 
                pictureBoxInput.Image = null;
                pictureBoxInput.Dispose();
                }

               if (pictureBoxOutput.Image != null) { 
            pictureBoxOutput.Image = null;
            pictureBoxOutput.Dispose();
            }



            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pathInput + "\\");

            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }

            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dia = new DirectoryInfo(pathOutput + "\\");
            foreach (FileInfo file in dia.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
```

But still having the same error when program tries to delete files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing:

```
if (pictureBoxInput.Image != null) { 
    pictureBoxInput.Image = null;
    pictureBoxInput.Dispose();
}
```

to:

```
if (pictureBoxInput.Image != null) { 
    var existingFile = pictureBoxInput.Image;
    pictureBoxInput.Image = null;
    existingFile?.Dispose();
}
```

*and the same for `pictureBoxOutput`*

The issue is that your existing code is disposing the *wrong thing* - you are disposing the `PictureBox` rather than the `Image` (and the `Image` is the thing that is holding the file lock).